# calling static method in java

Tags: java, static-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How come invoking a (static) method on a null reference doesn’t throw NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293353/how-come-invoking-a-static-method-on-a-null-reference-doesnt-throw-nullpointe)

Can any one explain why the output of the following program is "**Called**"

```
public class Test4{

  public static void method(){
    System.out.println("Called");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Test4 t4 = null;
    t4.method();
  }
}
```

I know we can call static method with class reference , but here I am calling using null reference . please clarify my doubt

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the Byte code

```
Test4 t4 = null;
t4.method();
```

will be

```
Test4 t4 = null;
Test4.method();
```

Compiler would convert the call with the class name for static methods. refer to this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752479/why-doesnt-this-code-throw-nullpointerexception) on SO which i myself have asked it.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if the instance is null, because you are calling a **static method.**
Think of it this way.

Every **static method** is equivalent with a **class method** whereas a **non-static method** is equivalent with 
an **instance method**.

Therefor it doesn't matter what value the instance takes as long as you are working with **static methods or members**.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods can be called via the classname or an instance.
I would try to avoid to call them by an instance (also a lot of tools warn you to do so because of bad practice).