# is there any difference between "invoking a static method with class name" and "invoking a static method with an object" in java?

Tags: java, static

in java we are able to "invoke a static method with class name" and also "invoke a static method with an object"
what is the difference between "invoking a static method with class name" and "invoking a static method with an object" in java?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752479/why-doesnt-this-code-throw-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, `new ClassName().staticMethod();` is considered as `ClassName.staticMethod()`. So there is no difference. It just causes confusion.
Consider an example

```
public class StaticDemo {

    static int staticVar = 10;

    public static void main(String [] args){

    System.out.println(new StaticDemo().staticVar);
    System.out.println(StaticDemo.staticVar);

    }

}
```

This outputs

```
10
10
```

`

**even if you write `new StaticDemo().staticVar`, it will be considered as `StaticDemo.staticVar`.** So there is no difference at all and always use the Class notation to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference but the recommendation is to call the `static` methods in a staic way i.e. using the ClassName. Generally static analayzers will report an error if you don't do so.

An important thing to understand here is that `static` method are stateless and hence calling them with an instance is confusing for someone reading your code. Because no matter what instance you use to call the `static` method, result will remain the same. This is because a `static` method belongs to a class but not to an object.

Comment: Yes, right on. The classic example of confusion is calling `anotherThread.sleep()` - of course, that's a static method and so the calling thread (rather than `anotherThread`) will be the one that sleeps.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is none. Apart from possible confusion... A reader of such code cannot reliably tell static from non static members/methods apart if you use an instance to access them:

```
public class X
{
    public static final String foo = "foo";
    public static String bar() { return "bar"; }

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        final X x = new X();
        System.out.println(X.foo); // "foo"
        System.out.println(x.foo); // "foo" too -- same reference
        System.out.println(X.bar()); // "bar"
        System.out.println(x.bar()); // "bar" too -- same reference
    }
}
```

As this is confusing, it is generally preferred to use the class to refer to such members/methods.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference at all. But since static methods are at the class level, you can access them using the class name. Though invoking them using class object is possible, it creates a confusion. Why would you like to invoke them for every object if its value is going to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Static methods do NOT operate on a `class`. They are just bound to class instead of to member of that class. This means that they don't have access to any `non static` members of the `class`. Other than that, they are not very different than the `non-static` methods.

Answer (score 0):

In SCJP guide book. having a example as following:

```
class Frog {
static int frogCount = 0; // Declare and initialize 
// static variable
public Frog() {
frogCount += 1; // Modify the value in the constructor
}
}
class TestFrog {
public static void main (String [] args) {
new Frog();
new Frog();
new Frog();
System.out.print("frogCount:"+Frog.frogCount); //Access 
// static variable 
}
}
```

> But just to make it really confusing, the Java language also allows
>   you to use an  object reference variable to access a static member

```
Frog f = new Frog();
int frogs = f.frogCount; // Access static variable 
// FrogCount using f
```

> In the preceding code, we instantiate a Frog, assign the new Frog
>   object to the  reference variable f, and then use the f reference to
>   invoke a staticmethod! But  even though we are using a specific Frog
>   instance to access the staticmethod,  the rules haven't changed. This
>   is merely a syntax trick to let you use an object  reference variable
>   (but not the object it refers to) to get to a staticmethod or 
>   variable, but the staticmember is still unaware of the particular
>   instance used  to invoke the staticmember. In the Frog example, the
>   compiler knows that the  reference variable f is of type Frog, and so
>   the Frog class staticmethod is run with  no awareness or concern for
>   the Frog instance at the other end of the f reference. In  other
>   words, the compiler cares only that reference variable f is declared
>   as type Frog.

I hope this will help you